# Creating a conditional NuGet package

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, powershell, nuget

I have created a custom assembly in C# which is going to be used by a number of different existing systems, there is quite a lot of configuration involved in getting this assembly working with our systems so to make things easier, we decided to create a local NuGet Server and roll the assembly into a NuGet package.

This worked perfectly well and we were able to add all the dependencies the assembly requires and add a web.config.transform file to merge in any additional nodes required.

This is where we hit our first stumbling block...

Firstly as I mentioned previously the assembly is written in C#, the application we are test running is written in VB.Net. As we are using `log4net` in the assembly we have implemented `WebActivatorEx` to ensure this was initialised on application startup, meaning we have an `AppStart` class which sits `App_Start` folder. However, after referring to the `WebActivatorEx` documentation we noticed that if the project is a **website** as apposed to a **web application** the `AppStart` class must sit inside the `App_Code` folder not the `App_Start` folder and must also use the `PostApplicationStartMethod` and not the `PreApplicationStartMethod`.

Also as the `AppStart` class is written in C# and will sit inside a VB.Net project we need this converting to VB only if the target project is VB to avoid messing around with more configuration files which is something we are trying to minimise.

In short, **the main questions here** are:

1. Can our NuGet package have some sort of **conditional behaviour**, i.e. if its a VB.Net project add the `AppStart` class in VB.Net and if its C#, leave it as C#.
2. If the project is a website place this `AppStart` class in the `App_Code` folder and use the `PostApplicationStartMethod`, if the project is a web application place the `AppStart` class in the `App_Start` folder and use the `PreApplicationStartMethod`.
3. Is this even the correct approach in terms of initialising log4net without re-writing the target application's global.asax
4. I'm aware you can run PowerShell commands inside the NuGet package, is there anyway of using this to work out whether the project is C# || VB or am I complicating things and should I simply create 4 different NuGet packages for each and every scenario but this seems plain wrong.

I will await and welcome any suggestions or comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the user is not modifying the appstart code you can just put the appstart code in a compiled assembly, that would avoid the vb.net vs. c#.

I'm also not sure why you need to use the PostApplicationStart vs. the PreApplicationStart. This is not an inherent difference between Web Site vs. Web application, you might want to look deeper into this. It's probably an ordering thing in the implementation of your specific Web Site.

Comment: I think OP is referring to the fact that you cannot use `PreApplicationStartMethod` in a Web Site due to the fact that the `App_Code` folder has not even compiled when that method is due to fire. `https://github.com/davidebbo/WebActivator` However OP needs to consider wether it is really necessary to init `log4net` this early on.

Comment: To be specific, I meant it doesn't matter for compiled assemblies. That's a very good point @generalexception

Comment: Ah fair point, so because the assembly is already compiled then a PreApplicationStartMethod would still work fine ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how Razor gets default using statements registered. And it obviously works in a web site scenario.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you will need to leverage the Init.ps1 and Install.ps1 support in NuGet. From their [documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#powershell):

- **Init.ps1** runs the first time a package is installed in a solution
- **Install.ps1** runs when a package is installed in a project.

  - **$project** is a reference to the EnvDTE project object and represents the project the package is installed into.

You should be able to use those scripts, and the specifically the special variable `$project` to determine the type of project you are installing your package into and make the appropriate adjustments to the project code. You can also use the helper cmdlet `Get-Project` in the Package Manager Console to get a reference to the [EnvDTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51h9a6ew(v=VS.80).aspx) object that will be passed to your Install.ps1 script. That should help in looking at the different properties and build up your conditional logic.

For example:

```
PM> $p = Get-Project
PM> $p.Type
C#
```

Reference: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#powershell